# In Vim, are there any differences between `d2d` and `2dd`?

Tags: vim

As far as I can tell, `d2d` and `2dd` have exactly the same effect.

I'm curious – ignoring any remappings of `d` and `2`, are there any cases in which `d2d` and `2dd` will produce a different result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

According to the Vim manual

> [count] An optional number that may precede
>   the command to multiply or iterate the
>   command.  If no number is given, a
>   count of one  is used, unless otherwise
>   noted.

Both commands will always produce the same result. If there is more than one count, then each count will be multiplied together. For example **2d2d** is equivalent to **4dd**, and **3d3d** is equivalent to **9dd**.

If you're only interested in just deleting two lines, you can save yourself an extra keystroke by using **dj**.